# Issue with testing sending a UDP packet with consoles

Tags: c#, .net, networking, udp

here is my code for the client

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string msg;
        Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 999);
        sck.Bind(ep);
        byte[] msgbytes;

        while (true)
        {
            msg = Console.ReadLine();
            msgbytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
            sck.BeginSendTo(msgbytes, 0, msgbytes.Length, SocketFlags.None, ep, null, sck);
            Console.WriteLine("sent");
        }
    }

    void callBack(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        ((Socket)result.AsyncState).EndSendTo(result);
    }
}
```

}

and here is server code

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string msg;
        Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 999);
        sck.Bind(ep);
        byte[] msgbytes = new byte[100];

        EndPoint client = (EndPoint)ep;

        int bytesrec;
        while (true)
        {
            bytesrec = sck.ReceiveFrom(msgbytes, 0, msgbytes.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref client);
            msg = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(msgbytes);
            Console.WriteLine("4");
        }
    }
}
```

}

The problem is no packet is ever received by the server when i try sending with the client. The "4" is never written, which confirms sck.receivefrom executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your client code change the following:
Instead of `sck.Bind(ep);` use `sck.Connect(ep);`
and instead of

```
sck.BeginSendTo(msgbytes, 0, msgbytes.Length, SocketFlags.None, ep, null, sck);
```

use

```
sck.Send(msgbytes, msgbytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
```

and it should work...

edit:
if you really need to use async send... you can do something like:

```
IAsyncResult asyncres = sck.BeginSendTo(msgbytes, 0, msgbytes.Length, SocketFlags.None, ep, null, sck);
sck.EndSendTo(asyncres);
```

Comment: -1. You cannot connect to an endpoint that you can bind to. The concept doesn't even begin to make sense. Please don't post mere untested guesswork here.

Comment: i was not connecting to an endpoint that i was binding. I told him to replace that code...

Comment: +1 ..BTW: Current `BeginSendTo` would also work, but I agree `Send` is better.

Comment: @avi I don't see any new value for 'ep' in your post, and neither the `connect()` nor indeed the `bind()` is necessary in the client at all.

Answer (score -2):

Your server needs to listen at 0.0.0.0, as it is doing, otherwise you are into the area of platform dependence; *and* your client needs to bind to an external IP address, not just 127.0.0.1, otherwise it has no way of ever sending any packet out of the local host.